# How to set up a boundary condition on the diagonal of a region that restricts a partial derivative?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

The problem is to solve the Laplace equation on a polygon with one of the boundary conditions specifying derivative on the boundary. Let us consider a polygon region.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
regionZup = 
  Polygon[{{(2 - Sqrt[2])/3, 
     2/3}, {(4 - Sqrt[2])/6, (4 - Sqrt[2])/6}, {1, 
     1}, {(2 - Sqrt[2])/3, 1}} ];
meshZup = ToElementMesh[regionZup, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01]
meshZup["Wireframe"]
```

The result is:

[image]

Let us now solve the equation **without** a boundary condition on the diagonal:

```
eq = Div[Grad[zz2[x1, x2], {x1, x2}].{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {x1, x2}];
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq == 0,
    DirichletCondition[zz2[x1, x2] == 0, x2 == (4 - Sqrt[2])/3 - x1],
    DirichletCondition[zz2[x1, x2] == 3*x2 - 2, x1 == (2 - Sqrt[2])/3],
    DirichletCondition[zz2[x1, x2] == 1, x2 == 1]},
   zz2, Element[{x1, x2}, meshZup]];

Plot3D[sol[x1, x2], Element[{x1, x2}, meshZup], 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> Full, PlotLabel -> "z2Init", 
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

Output:

[image]

However, the real problem involves the boundary condition on the diagonal x1==x2 the involves the partial derivative dzz2/dx2==1.5. If I include it as a part of Dirichlet condition:

```
eq = Div[Grad[zz2[x1, x2], {x1, x2}].{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {x1, x2}];
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq == 0,
    DirichletCondition[zz2[x1, x2] == 0, x2 == (4 - Sqrt[2])/3 - x1],
    DirichletCondition[zz2[x1, x2] == 3*x2 - 2, x1 == (2 - Sqrt[2])/3],
    DirichletCondition[zz2[x1, x2] == 1, x2 == 1],
    DirichletCondition[D[zz2[x1, x2], x2] == 1.5, x1 == x2]},
   zz2, Element[{x1, x2}, meshZup]];
```

I receive an error message:

```
NDSolveValue::fembdnl: The dependent variable in zz2$29542==1.5 in the boundary condition DirichletCondition[zz2$29542==1.5,x1==x2] needs to be linear.

NDSolveValue::fembdnl: The dependent variable in zz2$29569==1.5 in the boundary condition DirichletCondition[zz2$29569==1.5,x1==x2] needs to be linear.
```

After some research, I made a conclusion that the boundary condition on the derivative should be specified as a Neumann value. However, I cannot figure out how to specify a Neumann value that puts restriction only on the partial derivative.

Any help or reference would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.